# Select min/max from multiple items

Tags: mysql, minmax

I'll try to explain it as simple as possible:

First some database structure with dummy data.

## Structure

**tb_spec_fk**

```
feature     value
-----------------
1           1
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
2           2
2           3
3           1
3           4
4           2
4           3
4           4
5           1
5           3
5           5
6           3
6           5
```

**tb_spec_feature**

```
feature_id  filter
------------------
1           2
2           2
3           2
4           2
5           1
6           0
```

**tb_spec_value**

```
value_id    name
----------------
1           10
2           20
3           30
4           40
5           50
```

Now, what I want is the follow result

## Result

```
feature_id  min_value   max_value
---------------------------------
1           10          50
2           20          30
3           10          40
4           20          40
```

But how?

## Logic

Get from the tb_spec_feature where "filter" equals 2 the highest and lowest values which are present in the tb_spec_value table and connected together trough the tb_spec_fk table.

## My attemps

A lot! But I'll spare you :)

Comment: `My attemps
A lot! But I'll spare you :)` - No.. this is what we want to see, to see where you went wrong. Its much more beneficial to learn from your mistakes than to just have the answer.

Comment: How can you define your output? there seems to be no relation that two values come against one record

Comment: i dont understand how u get the max value and lowest value

Comment: I'll show my attempts in feature questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    f.feature_id AS feature_id,
    MAX(value.name) AS max_value,
    MIN(value.name) AS min_value
FROM tb_spec_feature AS f
    JOIN tb_spec_fk AS fk ON f.feature_id=fk.feature
    JOIN tb_spec_value AS value ON fk.value=value.id
WHERE f.filter=2
GROUP BY f.feature_id
```

The two `JOIN` statements "link" the a feature to a value. `GROUP BY` groups all rows with the same feature id, and then you can take the min or max or any other aggregate function on those columns.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a313/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and most important, I understand what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

```
select 
    tsf.feature_id,
    tsvl.name as Min_Value,
    tsvr.name as Max_Value
from tb_spec_feature as tsf
inner join (select feature , MIN(value) MinV,MAX(value)MaxV from tb_spec_fk group by feature order by feature)as tsfkl on tsfkl.feature = tsf.feature_id
left join tb_spec_value as tsvl on tsvl.value_id = tsfkl.MinV
left join tb_spec_value as tsvr on tsvr.value_id = tsfkl.MaxV
where tsf.filter = 2
group by tsf.feature_id
```

Output

```
feature_id  | Min_Value | Max_Value
---------------------------------
1           |   10      |   50
2           |   20      |   30
3           |   10      |   40
4           |   20      |   40
```

### Fiddle Demo